# Include youtube video player in html

Tags: html, youtube

Ok, there might be another similar question but couldn't find it.
Truth be told I didn't even knew what to look for.

I have the following piece of html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe width="560" height="315"
            src="//www.youtube.com/embed/q3rhteIierY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's all guys. Supposedly this should have worked.
But it's  not. I run it locally with no web-server.
I just want to embed a youtube player!

Any suggestions?

Comment: And it is - http://jsfiddle.net/oore4vgq/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try this for use with an iframe:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"
frameborder="0"/>
```

It's from Googles dev site: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Replace the URLs with your own values.

Comment: I used the snippet as it was given by the youtube.
Didn't see your answer before. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315"
            src="//www.youtube.com/embed/q3rhteIierY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

your src parameter is missing http:

try

```
        <iframe width="560" height="315"
            src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/q3rhteIierY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
```

Comment: You should not add http because the protocol is not necessarily http, it would be https or ftp or so on. And the actual protocol is https.

Comment: yes, but you have to determine protocol, otherwise browser do not know what to do with given source. ideally you can take iframe code directly from youtube video page.